# Questions within questions for tin can api?

Tags: tin-can-api

Does Tin Can API support questions within questions?

If so, what would be the specification for passing data to an LRS?

I was thinking of adding ID's to each sub question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much easier to answer if you could provide an example, but the flexibility of the Tin Can API is such that you can literally capture anything (which is also part of the complexity) with more or less grace.

Some immediate options come to mind:

- Use a single interaction activity statement (likely with type `choice`) and use the formatting allowed to have multi-value responses (i.e. `golf[,]tetris`).
- Use multiple statements where there is a combined statement (necessary if there is an overall result) such that there is a single main activity and each sub-question has its own statement where the sub-question has its own activity and the main activity would be stored in the `context.contextActivities.parent` list. When there is a combined statement in this case I would include a reference to the combined statement in the sub-question statements' `context.statement` property such that you can tie them all together.
- Use result, context, and activity definition `extensions` to capture anything. This should be a last resort option, it usually makes setting things up simple but adds significant complexity on the reporting side. Though tempting because of the simplicity, unless you are trying to capture a specific type of data point (like geo-location data, math equations, etc.) usually you should try to avoid the use of extensions.

Which of the above makes the most sense is probably determined by what sort of response is being given, and whether or not questions are nested such that there is an overall result and sub-results or whether there is just overall results.